# Will any mobs spawn in my barn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will any mobs spawn in my barn? nothing has yet but there is lots of light

[image]

There is most of the torches and the chicken just came in and the other was spawned by a egg

Here is another view

[image]

So there is a lot of torches and light. Will anything spawn?

Comment: I would personally worry more about the barn going down in flames than the possibility of mobs spawning in it. Just sayin'.

Comment: your barns lack of uniform is driving me crazy

Comment: Are you wanting passive mobs to spawn, or are you worried about hostile mobs showing up?

Answer (score 12):

I saw "barn" and the chicken, so I presumed you were trying to get passive mobs to spawn, but [gnovice's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61861/will-any-mobs-spawn-in-my-barn/61863#comment87100_61861) suggests two ways to answer this question:

#### Will any passive mobs/animals spawn?

Presumably you've been sticking close to your barn: while this would've worked fine in earlier versions of Minecraft, passive mob spawning changed before release such that they only have a very, very small chance of spawning in already-loaded chunks.

To get passive mobs, like chickens, to spawn with any useful frequency, you need to either:

- walk far enough away such that you load new chunks, which will supposedly have [a 1/10 chance of spawning new passive mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Animal_Spawning) (although this is deterministic based on your world seed), or
- find a couple of passive mobs and [breed them](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding).

#### Will any hostile mobs spawn?

Hostile mobs will spawn at [light levels 7 or lower](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Effects_of_light), and torches have a light level of 14. From your screenshot, it looks like your barn is a rectangular, 11x9 room. It also looks like you have torches across the entire bottom row of your barn's walls. Assuming that's the case, your barn's light map looks something like this:

[image: Light map of current torch situation]

So given your current setup, no mobs will spawn in your barn because the darkest part of the barn is still light level 9. This should also suggest two things to you:

- All of the other torches you have above the ring around the bottom are useless: the bottom ring supersedes them.
- You can move that bottom ring up one level and still have a hostile mob-proof room (the center area would be light level 8).

You could also be a bit more efficient with your torches: for example, you don't need torches on the shorter walls if you use torches across the longer walls:

[image: Light map of shorter wall torches removed]

You can even light up the place with only 6 torches:

[image: Efficient torch placement light map]

Comment: As a sidenote - once you actually find passive mobs at a distance from your barn, you can use Wheat to lure them back. Animals will follow you as long as you are holding a piece of wheat in your hand.

Comment: i know but i want them to spawn passive mods i mean sorry i didnt say that :)

Comment: @sapphire See the first part of my answer then; you need to load new chunks for passive mobs to spawn: light has very little effect on passive mob spawning.

Answer (score 1):

Mobs are spawned at chunk generation, after this they will spawn if there are very few around, but very slowly indeed.

The best way to fill your barn with animals is to go out and find them in new chunks and lure them back with wheat, carrots (for pigs), or seeds (for chicken).

Comment: Chickens require seeds.

Comment: Not entirely true. If the number of living passive mob packs in the area drops, new passive mob packs *sloooowly* spawn under the same conditions they used to (lighted, on grass).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did not know that.

Comment: It's so slow that it's useless for trapping, but fast enough that you can go on a slaughtering spree and not be doomed to a lifeless wasteland forever. The only useful thing about it is if you can't find a certain kind of mob; then killing off packs of whatever is abundant will give room for new spawns that eventually might be of the sort you're looking for.

Comment: I just took a look at the code (goddamn that is spaghetti code). I can't tell how often it checks, but each time it does it will only spawn a new animal pack if the number of still-living individual (I think) animals spawned in that chunk is <4.

Answer (score 0):

Mobs cannot spawn on non-opaque blocks. This includes half-blocks, and blocks with torches, rails or basically anything weird on them. I would try *half blocks*. They look pretty, and if you have the rest of the earth covered with them inside, 0% chance of spawns.